# Whats the best program to use to make ebooks

Tags: sigil

I've been using Sigil so far to make epubs but i was wondering if there's any better programs i could use, preferably free but doesn't have to be, that would be more efficient. 
The bulk of the books i'll be making have a lot of footnotes, finding solutions to issues i have with Sigil is very difficult and time consuming so it would be useful to have something that's better known. 
Thanks

Comment: At the moment your question seems to expect a rather opinion based answer. But that'S unfortunately not what SE sites are for. So please try to refactor your question, to make it more precisely. You could for example define your current drawbacks regarding Sigil in more details to allow others to propose a better alternative for you.

Comment: I really just want to know what other options are out there to be honest, there's no major issue I have with Sigil but I'd like to compare it against what else is out there to see if there is a more efficient way to do things, or if Sigil is the best way then it'll give me some piece of mind that I'm doing it the best way I can. I've tried using Google to find out what people are using but don't seem to be finding any names of programs that work with the actual making of epubs, only things like calibre

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about sigil, but I have made a book with footnotes, and I have been using an xml editor with docbook to generate an epub with  footnotes. Works well.

Unless you're already fluent in docbook, I suspect you wouldn't want to learn that.

Adobe InDesign already has a functionality to convert footnotes into epub http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/export-content-epub-cc.html#reflowable_export_options Indesign is a real bear, but the monthly rental rates for the software might make it a good option for you.